# Internal link in xslt does not work

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some problem regarding following `xslt` file.

1. TO TOP does not work very well. It work only on top of page but when I am scrolling down then it is going not to be as a link.
2. internal Link does not work properly. It writes the the text as seems to be linked but only the text is written as a link and it does not work anymore.

Can you please help me how can I fix them?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="SquishReport/test">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>

                #header {text-align:left;padding:5px;}

                #nav {line-height:25px;width:1400px;float:left;padding:5px;}

                #section {position:relative;left:20px;top:50px;}

                #top {width:200px;position:fixed;top: 60px;right: 5px;}

                table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;} 

                th, td {padding:2px}

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div id="header">
                <h2> Squish-Testauswertung(<xsl:value-of select="epilog/attribute::time"/>)</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="nav">
                <h3>Summary</h3>
                <table>
                    <xsl:for-each select="test">
                        <xsl:variable name="LinkIt" select="attribute::name"/>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="descendant::node()/attribute::type='FAIL'">
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="red"><a href="#{$LinkIt}" title="click for Information"><xsl:value-of select="$LinkIt"/></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="message/attribute::type='ERROR'">
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="yellow"><a href="#{$LinkIt}" title="click for Information"><xsl:value-of select="$LinkIt"/></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="message/attribute::type='FATAL'">
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="coral"><a href="#{$LinkIt}" title="click for Information"><xsl:value-of select="$LinkIt"/></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="descendant::node()/attribute::type='PASS'">
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="lime"><a href="#{$LinkIt}" title="click for Information"><xsl:value-of select="$LinkIt"/></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div id="top">
                <a href="#" title="To the top of this page"><b>TO TOP</b></a>
                <br/>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <td>Log</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="20" bgcolor="yellow"></th>
                        <td>Error</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th bgcolor="coral"></th>
                        <td>Fatal</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th bgcolor="red"></th>
                        <td>Fail</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th bgcolor="lime"></th>
                        <td>Pass</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div id="section">
                <h3>Details</h3>

                <table>
                    <tr bgcolor="Peru">
                        <th>Testname</th>
                        <th>Logs</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="test">
                        <xsl:variable name="LogNum" select="count(message)" />
                        <xsl:variable name="VerifNum" select="count(verification)"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="LinkName" select="attribute::name"/>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="{$LogNum+$VerifNum+1}" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;position:"><a name="#{$LinkName}"><xsl:value-of select="$LinkName"/></a></th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::node()">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="attribute::type='LOG'">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="attribute::type='FATAL'">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="coral"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="attribute::type='ERROR'">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="yellow"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="attribute::type='FAIL'">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="red"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="attribute::type='PASS'">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="lime"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean without a verifiable example. It is a good thing you showed your code, but to run it and test it we would also need a (minimal!) input XML document that shows this erroneous behavior. If you need suggestions setting this up, have a look at SO's help page [mcve].

Comment: I think is more an HTML issue than an XSLT issue. Before you try writing XSLT, you should really first know what output your want. So, you need to work out what your HTML needs to look like if you were writing it out my hand in a text editor. If you are struggling with the HTML, take a look at this question for starters:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370867/go-to-top-of-browser-using-xslt.

Comment: Here are a couple of hints: (1) Instead of writing `attribute::name` in your match expressions, you can just put `@name`. (2) Instead of `descendant::node()/attribute::type`, put `*/@type`. Also please supply a simple example input document and the expected output.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: `descendant::node()` is _not_ the same as `*`, which is `child::*`, which is `child::element()`. In this case you can use `*` because there will only be element nodes that have an attribute, but you cannot replace `descendant` for the `child` axis (unless, of course, the descendant axis was not meant in the first place).

Comment: @Abel In general, you are right, but in the particular spot where he was using it, I was making an assumption about his intention. I could be wrong, but I don't think he actually intended `decendant::` . The OP needs to clarify with some test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have assumed that you are using [Squishy format version 3](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rg-regressiontesting.html), and that your test cases are not nested.

If your input document is, for example, ...

```
<SquishReport xmlns="http://www.froglogic.com/resources/schemas/xml3" version="3">
  <test type="testsuite">
    <prolog time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:00">
      <name>My test suite</name>
    </prolog>

  <test type="testcase">
    <prolog time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:00">
        <name>Test case 1</name>
        <location>
          <uri>http://www.abc.net.au</uri>
        </location>
      </prolog>
    <verification>
        <location>
          <uri>x-testcase:/unit1.pas</uri>
          <lineNo>2</lineNo>
        </location>
    <scriptedVerificationResult time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:01" type="PASS">
      <text>Summed a column of numbers</text>
      <detail>The sum was correct</detail>
    </scriptedVerificationResult>  
    </verification>
    <verification>
        <location>
          <uri>x-testcase:/unit1.pas</uri>
          <lineNo>6</lineNo>
        </location>
    <propertyVerificationResult time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:01" type="PASS" />
    </verification>
    <verification>
        <location>
          <uri>x-testcase:/unit2.pas</uri>
          <lineNo>3</lineNo>
        </location>
    <screenshotVerificationResult time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:02" type="ERROR" />
    </verification>
    <message time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:03" type="LOG">This is a log message</message>
    <message time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:04" type="WARNING">This is a warning</message>
    <message time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:05" type="FATAL">Fatality!</message>
    <epilog time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:06"/>
  </test>

  <test type="testcase">
    <prolog time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:07">
        <name>Test case 2</name>
        <location>
          <uri>http://feedly.com</uri>
        </location>
      </prolog>
    <verification>
        <location>
          <uri>x-testcase:/unit2.pas</uri>
          <lineNo>5</lineNo>
        </location>
    <scriptedVerificationResult time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:08" type="FAIL">
      <text>Something went wrong</text>
      <detail>Stack overflow</detail>
    </scriptedVerificationResult>  
    </verification>
    <epilog time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:09"/>
  </test>


  <epilog time="2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:10"/>
  </test>
</SquishReport>
```

... then this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:sq="http://www.froglogic.com/resources/schemas/xml3"
  version="1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="sq">  

<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="sq:test" mode="summary">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="
    (sq:verification/sq:scriptedVerificationResult  [@type='FAIL'] |
     sq:verification/sq:screenshotVerificationResult[@type='FAIL'] |
     sq:verification/sq:propertyVerificationResult  [@type='FAIL'] |
     sq:verification/sq:tableVerificationResult     [@type='FAIL'] 
     )[1]" mode="summary" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="
    (sq:verification/sq:scriptedVerificationResult  [@type='FATAL'] |
     sq:verification/sq:screenshotVerificationResult[@type='FATAL'] |
     sq:verification/sq:propertyVerificationResult  [@type='FATAL'] |
     sq:verification/sq:tableVerificationResult     [@type='FATAL'] | 
     sq:message                                     [@type='FATAL'] 
     )[1]" mode="summary" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="
    (sq:verification/sq:scriptedVerificationResult  [@type='ERROR'] |
     sq:verification/sq:screenshotVerificationResult[@type='ERROR'] |
     sq:verification/sq:propertyVerificationResult  [@type='ERROR'] |
     sq:verification/sq:tableVerificationResult     [@type='ERROR'] 
     )[1]" mode="summary" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="
    (sq:verification/sq:scriptedVerificationResult  [@type='PASS'] |
     sq:verification/sq:screenshotVerificationResult[@type='PASS'] |
     sq:verification/sq:propertyVerificationResult  [@type='PASS'] |
     sq:verification/sq:tableVerificationResult     [@type='PASS'] 
     )[1]" mode="summary" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="sq:message[@type='WARNING'][1]" mode="summary" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@type">
    <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".='FAIL'"   >red</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=".='FATAL'"  >coral</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=".='ERROR'"  >yellow</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=".='PASS'"   >lime</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=".='WARNING'">amber</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>  
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="sq:scriptedVerificationResult   |
                     sq:screenshotVerificationResult |
                     sq:propertyVerificationResult   |
                     sq:tableVerificationResult      |
                     sq:message" mode="summary">
  <tr><td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@type" />
    <a href="{
      self::node()[not(self::sq:message)]/../../sq:prolog/sq:location/sq:uri/text() |
      self::sq:message/../sq:prolog/sq:location/sq:uri/text() 
    }" title="click for Information">
      <xsl:value-of select="
        self::node()[not(self::sq:message)]/../../sq:prolog/sq:name |
        self::sq:message/../sq:prolog/sq:name
      " />
    </a>
  </td></tr>                                 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Squish-Testauswertung</title>
  </head> 
  <body>
<div id="header">
<h2>Squish-Testauswertung(2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:00)</h2>
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <h3>Summary</h3>
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sq:SquishReport/sq:test/sq:test[@type='testcase']" mode="summary" />
  </table>
</div>   

<div id="top">
  <br/>
  <table>
    <tr><th width="20" >&#160;</th> <td>Log</td></tr>
    <tr><th bgcolor="yellow"></th><td>Error</td></tr>
    <tr><th bgcolor="coral"></th><td>Fatal</td></tr>
    <tr><th bgcolor="amber"></th><td>Warning</td></tr>
    <tr><th bgcolor="red"></th><td>Fail</td></tr>
    <tr><th bgcolor="lime"></th><td>Pass</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="section">
  <h3>Details</h3>
    <table>
      <tr bgcolor="Peru"><th>Testname</th><th>Logs</th></tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="sq:SquishReport/sq:test/sq:test[@type='testcase']" />
   </table>
</div>
<br/>
<a href="#header" title="To the top of this page"><b>TO TOP</b></a>

</body>  
</html>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sq:test">
  <tr><th
        rowspan="{count( sq:verification | sq:message) + 1}"
        style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;position:">
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="sq:prolog/sq:location/sq:uri" />
      </xsl:attribute>  
      <xsl:value-of select="sq:prolog/sq:name" />
    </a></th></tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="sq:verification | sq:message" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sq:verification[sq:scriptedVerificationResult]">
   <tr><td>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="sq:scriptedVerificationResult/@type" />
     <xsl:value-of select="sq:scriptedVerificationResult/sq:detail" />
   </td></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sq:verification[sq:screenshotVerificationResult]">
   <tr><td>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="sq:screenshotVerificationResult/@type" />
     <xsl:text>screenshotVerificationResult</xsl:text>
   </td></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sq:verification[sq:propertyVerificationResult]">
   <tr><td>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="sq:propertyVerificationResult/@type" />
     <xsl:text>propertyVerificationResult</xsl:text>
   </td></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sq:verification[sq:tableVerificationResult]">
   <tr><td>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="sq:tableVerificationResult/@type" />
     <xsl:text>tableVerificationResult</xsl:text>
   </td></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sq:message">
   <tr><td>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@type" />
     <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
   </td></tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will yield a result like this ....

```css
#header {text-align:left;padding:5px;}
#nav {line-height:25px;width:1400px;float:left;padding:5px;}
#section {left:20px;top:50px;}
#top {width:200px;position:fixed;top: 60px;right: 5px;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;} 
th, td {padding:2px}
```

```html
<div id="header">
      <h2>Squish-Testauswertung(2015-06-19T11:22:27+02:00)</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <h3>Summary</h3>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="coral"><a href="http://www.abc.net.au" title="click for Information">Test case 1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="yellow"><a href="http://www.abc.net.au" title="click for Information">Test case 1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="lime"><a href="http://www.abc.net.au" title="click for Information">Test case 1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="amber"><a href="http://www.abc.net.au" title="click for Information">Test case 1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="red"><a href="http://feedly.com" title="click for Information">Test case 2</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="top"><br><table>
        <tr>
          <th width="20"> </th>
          <td>Log</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="yellow"></th>
          <td>Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="coral"></th>
          <td>Fatal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="amber"></th>
          <td>Warning</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="red"></th>
          <td>Fail</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="lime"></th>
          <td>Pass</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
      <h3>Details</h3>
      <table>
        <tr bgcolor="Peru">
          <th>Testname</th>
          <th>Logs</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="7" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;position:"><a name="http://www.abc.net.au">Test case 1</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="lime">The sum was correct</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="lime">propertyVerificationResult</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="yellow">screenshotVerificationResult</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="">This is a log message</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="amber">This is a warning</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="coral">Fatality!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;position:"><a name="http://feedly.com">Test case 2</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="red">Stack overflow</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div><br><a href="#header" title="To the top of this page"><b>TO TOP</b></a></body>
```